# Repeat a weekly query multiple times in 1 yearly query

Tags: mysql

I have a query which gives me the result of how many times a 'search_term' is used in 1 week. This is the following query

```
SELECT search_term, COUNT(DISTINCT log_search.id) AS search_count, COUNT(DISTINCT log_search.user_id) AS unique_search_count 
FROM log_search 
LEFT JOIN log_session_start ON log_session_start.gg = log_search.gg
WHERE log_search.search_term = 'christmas' AND log_search.date_id >= 20140101 AND log_search.date_id <=20140131 AND log_session_start.site_id=1;
```

As you can see i use the log_search.date_id to specifie a given week in the year. Now i want to have the results of all the weeks of a give year, for example year 2014. I can repeat this query 52 times in PHP but that is not what i want. I want So i came up whith the next query.

```
   SELECT  
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140106 AND log_search.date_id <=20140112 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w1,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140113 AND log_search.date_id <=20140119 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w2,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140120 AND log_search.date_id <=20140126 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w3,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140127 AND log_search.date_id <=20140202 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w4,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140203 AND log_search.date_id <=20140209 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w5,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140210 AND log_search.date_id <=20140216 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w6,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140217 AND log_search.date_id <=20140223 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w7,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140224 AND log_search.date_id <=20140302 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w8,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140303 AND log_search.date_id <=20140309 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w9,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140310 AND log_search.date_id <=20140316 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w10,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140317 AND log_search.date_id <=20140323 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w11,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140324 AND log_search.date_id <=20140330 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w12,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140331 AND log_search.date_id <=20140406 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w13,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140407 AND log_search.date_id <=20140413 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w14,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140414 AND log_search.date_id <=20140420 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w15,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140421 AND log_search.date_id <=20140427 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w16,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140428 AND log_search.date_id <=20140504 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w17,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140505 AND log_search.date_id <=20140511 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w18,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140512 AND log_search.date_id <=20140518 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w19,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140519 AND log_search.date_id <=20140525 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w20,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140526 AND log_search.date_id <=20140601 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w21,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140602 AND log_search.date_id <=20140608 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w22,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140609 AND log_search.date_id <=20140615 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w23,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140616 AND log_search.date_id <=20140622 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w24,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140623 AND log_search.date_id <=20140629 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w25,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140630 AND log_search.date_id <=20140706 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w26,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140707 AND log_search.date_id <=20140713 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w27,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140714 AND log_search.date_id <=20140720 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w28,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140721 AND log_search.date_id <=20140727 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w29,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140728 AND log_search.date_id <=20140803 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w30,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140804 AND log_search.date_id <=20140810 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w31,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140811 AND log_search.date_id <=20140817 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w32,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140818 AND log_search.date_id <=20140824 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w33,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140825 AND log_search.date_id <=20140831 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w34,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140901 AND log_search.date_id <=20140907 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w35,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140908 AND log_search.date_id <=20140914 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w36,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140915 AND log_search.date_id <=20140921 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w37,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140922 AND log_search.date_id <=20140928 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w38,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20140929 AND log_search.date_id <=20141005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w39,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141006 AND log_search.date_id <=20141012 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w40,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141013 AND log_search.date_id <=20141019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w41,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141020 AND log_search.date_id <=20141026 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w42,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141027 AND log_search.date_id <=20141102 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w43,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141103 AND log_search.date_id <=20141109 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w44,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141110 AND log_search.date_id <=20141116 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w45,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141117 AND log_search.date_id <=20141123 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w46,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141124 AND log_search.date_id <=20141130 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w47,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141201 AND log_search.date_id <=20141207 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w48,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141208 AND log_search.date_id <=20141214 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w49,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141215 AND log_search.date_id <=20141221 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w50,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141222 AND log_search.date_id <=20141228 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w51,
COUNT( NULLIF( (CASE WHEN log_search.date_id >= 20141229 AND log_search.date_id <=20150104 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0 )) AS w52
FROM log_search 
LEFT JOIN log_session_start ON log_session_start.gg = log_search.gg
WHERE log_search.search_term = 'christmas' AND log_session_start.site_id=1;
```

The problem of this query is that it only gives me the 'search_count' and not the 'unique_search_count'.

I'm trying to figure out how i can repeat the 1st query, 52 times, in 1 query (like the 2nd query). Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not get all the hits for the year along with date, then count the weekly hits in your client code?

Comment: Good question... Yes, that is possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're bothered with the second query about it showing the 'search_results' and not the 'unique_search_results', you could just run the query with [group by](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) added to it. It'll show the results grouped up that have the same search result. I dont understand your query fully but if you want the count of all the unique_search_results, you could use a `group by`

Comment: How can i add the alias 'search_count' and 'unique_search_count' in the second query?